# IIS FTP Block Specific File Uploads

Tags: security, iis, ftp

We host numerous ftp sites on a single Windows 2003 server (using IIS and Active Directory to manage the sites and users).

One of the sites is public (unrestricted), but we have a bot that's been uploading index.php/index.html/.htaccess files every day.

Since it's a public site, there's nothing really there that can be comprimised, but it's annoying to have to flush these files every day. Is there a way to restrict uploads by *filename*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a file there w/ permissions such that it can't be overwritten (or read, if you're worried about someone downloading the "dummy" files). Then, at least, the "bot" wouldn't be able to keep uploading.

There isn't much modularity in the IIS FTP server like there is with the web server (you can't write ISAPI filter modules to intercept request-related events, etc). You're, more or less, just going to have to work around the unintended behavior or switch to an FTP server that has the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Evan. I figured as much, but figured it wouldn't hurt to ask ;)